# Can notes and attachment email alert via workflow possible?

Tags: email, workflow, email-alert

Is it possible to do a 
**email alert workflow
** 
only everytime a file is uploaded in notes and attachment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it is not possible via Workflow as Attachments and Notes are phantom objects so not available via workflow but you can write trigger on Attachment object which will complete your requirement.

Comment: I did manage to create a check box that will create an alert if the box is true then added a field update to put the check box to false after save.

It's an extra step but oh well.

Comment: how did you accomplish that workaround? I'd be interested in learning!